# random returning (g, g) instead of (Double, g)?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I have this snippet of code:

```
  markovNextSS :: (RandomGen g, Ord a) => (MarkovChain a, a, g) -> (MarkovChain a, a, g)
  markovNextSS (chain, prev, gen) = let
    (gen', roll) = randomR (0.0, 1.0) gen
    -- expected to get a (Double, g) above,
    -- but GHC 7.8.3 says that this is a (g, g) instead
    next = markovNext chain prev roll
    in (chain, next, gen')
```

Why would GHC be inferring the wrong type above, especially if `RandomGen` is not an instance of `Random`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `gen'` and `roll` backwards in your `randomR` invocation. GHC knows the second arg has to be of the same type as `gen` due to `randomR`'s definition, and knows that the first arg has to be `g` because it's returned in a context where it has to be `g`. So it turns up an unhelpful error like that when it eventually runs into a contradiction with this train of logic.

As a tip, when you run into things like this, start adding `expr :: Type` annotations in the middle of your code with what you think is the correct type. It'll help force the contradiction to happen at the point where the actual error lies.